# Angular scrolling to a location in different page

Tags: angularjs, scroll, router, route-provider

I have a SPA with an `index.htm` and two pages - `home.htm` & `signup.htm` that gets routed to using angular's `$routeProvider` & `ng-view` directive.

On the nav bar, I got `about-us`, `contact`, `signup` links & clicking them should take me to the corresponding sections of `about-us -> home.htm`, `contact -> home.htm`, `signup -> signup.htm`

Below is my angular code that I have to accomplish the same. The `$location.hash` method does not seem to be changing even though I reset it for different param values. The `#` value seems to be set at contact always. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
var ub = angular.module('ub',['ngRoute']);

ub.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider

    .when('/',{
        templateUrl: '../pages/home.htm',
        controller:'mainController'
    })

    .when('/signup',{
        templateUrl: '../pages/signup.htm',
        controller:'signupController'
    })

    .when('/services/:id',{
        templateUrl: '../pages/home.htm',
        controller:'mainController'
    })

    .when('/about/:id',{
        templateUrl: '../pages/home.htm',
        controller:'mainController'
    })

    .when('/contact/:id',{
        templateUrl: '../pages/home.htm#contact',
        controller:'mainController'
    })
});

ub.controller('mainController',['$scope','$log','$location','$anchorScroll','$routeParams',function($scope,$log,$location,$anchorScroll,$routeParams){

    console.log($routeParams.id);
    switch($routeParams.id)
    {
        case "2":
        $location.hash('services');     
        $anchorScroll();
        case "3":
        $location.hash('about');        
        $anchorScroll();
        case "4":
        $location.hash('contact');      
        $anchorScroll();
    };


}]);

ub.controller('signupController',['$scope','$log',function($scope,$log){
    console.log('we are inside signup controller');
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `break;` statement in the cases of switch, also must use just one route, in the route provider for `home.htm` and in the routeparams you would have to pass the id and change the hash url alone

```
$routeProvider

.when('/home/:id',{
    templateUrl: '../pages/home.htm',
    controller:'mainController'
})

.when('/signup',{
    templateUrl: '../pages/signup.htm',
    controller:'signupController'
})
```

Controller,

```
switch($routeParams.id)
{
    case "2":
    $location.hash('services');     
    $anchorScroll();
    break;
    case "3":
    $location.hash('about');        
    $anchorScroll();
    break;
    case "4":
    $location.hash('contact');      
    $anchorScroll();

};
```

Comment: Thanks Shintu. It works now. I had to change the route pattern to "/home/:id" otherwise angular took signup also as an route parameter value

Comment: Good to know @RajkumarKaliyaperumal, If it is fine pls mark it as answer